# Using JOptionPane

Tags: java, joptionpane

if i was using a JOptionPane message dialog box how would I be able to show an the whole array in the message section  such as this little snipit? or would that evenbe possible?

```
 public void showTheMessage()

{
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"These are are all the colors to
          choosfrom,\n"+ arrayOfcolors[the whole array], "Color box");
 }
```

Comment: Yes it is extremely easy to do, but I've noticed that you never bother to accept any of the answers you get, which means you don't appreciate all the help you've received over the last couple of months. So, I'll spend my time helping others.

Comment: @camickr I did not know how to do that until just now cause some one showed me to do this ten minutes ago so please dont try to insult me before you know what is going on with that. I had asked before and just got the answer now so I am sorry if you think I dont appreciate the help just didn't know how. I do leave alot of comments.

Comment: @camickr I just accepted all the ones i used and understood a little. God Bless and I dont intend to be rude just tired and have this project due on monday and was only able to start this one today. I just finished the other one That i kept asking questions about the months but I do understand what you are saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be to concatenate all the elements of the array into one big string.

```
String colors = "";
for(int i = 0; i < arrayOfColors.length; i++)
    colors += arrayOfColors[i] + " ";
```

Comment: exactly what i was looking for but some strange reason i could not think of how to do this array or loop and I had one similar. God Bless thanks alot

Comment: What does showing all the colors do, if the user can't select one? There is a better solution to the problem.

Comment: @camicker-I am working on a school project using javax.swing package and I just need to display all the colors i have in that array on the JOptionPane's show messageDialog box. This worked just for the display part.

Answer (score 0):

The [showOptionDialog](http://tinyurl.com/yk9oess) method lets the user select a single element from an array of options, which I think is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In case its an array of Color objects

```
   String colors="";
   for (Color c: arrayOfColors) 
       colors+= c.toString() + " ";
```

Otherwise if its an array of String objects

```
   String colors="";
   for (String s: arrayOfColors) 
       colors+= s + " ";
```

Just a note, using StringBuilder is much faster, but this is just a small array i guess.